# How to convert a 4-channel image to 3-channel image in an elegant way?

Tags: image-processing

I have a 4-channel image (RGBA). I want to reduce its channel count from 4 to 3.

The method I am using currently is to **Right click** and **Save as** a `.png` file. After that when I `Import` it in Mathematica, the channel count is reduced to 3. Is there a more elegant way to do that?

**Note**: `RemoveAlphaChannel[]` function won't work. Because that will change the appearance of the original image (see the example below).

This is a 4-channel picture from [ref / AlphaChannel](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RemoveAlphaChannel.html):

[image: 4-channel picture]

```
 img = Import @ "https://i.stack.imgur.com/XvzDc.png"
```

This is the 3-channel picture which is what I want:

[image: 3-channel picture]

If I use `RemoveAlphaChannel[]`, I will get this picture instead:

[image: Picture after RemoveAlphaChannel]

Comment: does `RemoveAlphaChannel[img, White]` not work for you? it does give 3-channel image ( `ImageChannels@RemoveAlphaChannel[img, White]` is 3).

Comment: @kglr Yes it works for that situation. It's amazing, thank you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The second example from [`RemoveAlphaChannel`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RemoveAlphaChannel.html):

> - Remove opacity by blending with a white background:

```
img2 = RemoveAlphaChannel[img, White]
```

[image]

```
ImageChannels /@ {img, img2}
```

> {4, 3}

```
ColorSeparate /@ {img, img2} // Grid
```

[image]

```
Row[{Labeled[Framed@AlphaChannel@img, "img", Top], 
     Labeled[Framed@AlphaChannel@img2, "img2", Top]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much @kglr. I wonder if `RemoveAlphaChannel[#, White]&` is universal. If it also works for various alpha channels. (I've tried some pictures with different alpha channels and it works, but I am still not sure whether it works for all the cases...)

Comment: @VoldikSS, I am not sure if it works for all cases.

Answer (score 3):

@kglr 's solution is very convenient and powerful. However `RemoveAlphaChannel[#, colorname]&` does not work for all cases. So I spent some time searching in the web forimage channels andfound the principle of the [alpha channel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_compositing).

Based on that, I get the following solution which can be used for other cases(different images with different alpha channels).

```
reduceImageChannels[img_] :=
 Map[Most,
    Map[(#*#[[4]] + 1*(1 - #[[4]])) &,
     (Flatten[ImageData@img, 1])]] // Partition[#, First@ImageDimensions[img]] & // Image
```

Let's check it,

```
img = Import @ "https://i.stack.imgur.com/XvzDc.png"
```

[image]

```
img2 = reduceImageChannels@img
```

[image]

```
ImageChannels@img2
```

> 3

It given me the image exactly what I want!

Comment: I haven't ran the code, but `Most` gives all but the last element of a list. And what is `120` doing there, is that something to do with the `ImageDimensions`?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I will replace `Drop[#, {4}] &` with `Most`. You are right, `ImageDimensions@img` returns `{120,120}`

Comment: you can also use `reduceImageChannels2[img_] :=  Map[Most[#*#[[4]] + 1*(1 - #[[4]])] &, ImageData@img, {2}]`

Comment: @kglr Thanks, it's much more elegant! I even forgot the `Map`'s `levelspec` option...

Comment: this looks like what `RemoveAlphaChannel[img,White]` does (_"blending all pixels with the background color"_ `White`)  which is the same as averaging pixel values with 1 (White) with weights equal to the value of the alpha channel (`#[[4]]`), but somehow, there are some differences between `ImageData[RemoveAlphaChannel[img, White]]` and `ImageData@Image@ reduceImageChannels[img]`.

Comment: @kglr Yes, I also found the data difference between those two method... but I don't understand what `RemoveAlphaChannel[image,c]`(by a parameter `c`) really does.

Comment: @Voldikss, `ImageData@ImageApply[Most[#*#[[4]] + 1*(1 - #[[4]])] &, img]` gives the same result as `ImageData[RemoveAlphaChannel[img, White]]`.

Comment: @kglr Really? But they are a little different in my PC. `reduceImageChannels@img // ImageData` returns `{{{1., 1., 1.}, {1., 1., 1.}, {0.99917, 0.999077, 0.997509}...}}` but `RemoveAlphaChannel[img, White]//ImageData` returns `{{{1., 1., 1.}, {1., 1., 1.}, {1., 1., 0.996078}, {1., 1., 0.996078},...}}`

Comment: yes there are (somehow) small differences probably (probably due to numerical precision)

Comment: for an arbitrary color in the second argument,say `Orange`, `RemoveAlphaChannel[img, Orange]`  and `ImageApply[Most[#]*#[[4]] + {1, 0.5, 0}*(1 - #[[4]]) &, img]` gives the same image as `ImageApply[Most[#]*#[[4]] + {1, 0.5, 0}*(1 - #[[4]]) &, img]` (that is, `Max@(ImageData@
    ImageApply[Most[#]*#[[4]] + {1, 0.5, 0}*(1 - #[[4]]) &, img] - 
   ImageData[RemoveAlphaChannel[img, Orange]])` .)  Note that `Orange` is `RGBColor[1,.5,0]`.

Comment: @kglr Amazing! Now I know what `RemoveAlphaChannel[image,c]` does, thanks.